# Como fazer um link ao clicar em uma div

Tags: jquery

Eu me esqueci como fazer links com jQuery que executam ao clicar em uma div. O link que eu precisava era com target blank.

Achei isso daqui mas não entendi o código e não conseguir usar.

```
jquery('a[href="http://site.com"]').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: Esse código pega todos os links (tag `<a href...>`) e coloca target blank. Não parece bem isso o que você quer. O que você quer que aconteça quando clicar na div?

Comment: Quando eu clicar na div carro quero que execute um determinado link em target blank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para abrir em uma nova janela utilize `window.open` (como bfavaretto alertou):

```
$('#minhadiv').click(function(){
    window.open('http://www.google.com');
});
```

Para abrir na mesma janela utilize `window.location`:

```
$('#minhadiv').click(function(){
    window.location='www.google.com';
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Rq37/1/

Comment: Para abrir em outra janela/aba: `window.open('http://www.google.com');`

Comment: Tinha me esquecido do window.location, obrigado!

Comment: Não esquece do CSS: `#minhadiv { cursor: pointer; }`. Por questões de usabilidade!